# Is there any shell command to setup aws credentials under a specific profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I want to set up my MFA profile credentials(i.e AceessKeyId, SecrectAccessKey, SessionToken) in `~/.aws/credentials` file. Is there any shell command to do this thing?

For example: if I execute `aws configure set default.aws_secret_access_key 'myaccesskey'` then credentials file is getting updated with this given access key.
 But if I type the same command with `aws configure set mfa.aws_secret_access_key 'myaccesskey'`, it is not updating in credentials file, instead `~/.aws/config` file is going to update with the format as shown below.

```
mfa =
    aws_secret_access_key = myaccesskey
```

My goal is, `~/.aws/credentials` file should be updated under MFA profile. Like

```
[default]
aws_secret_access_key = ****
****** = ******
[mfa]
aws_secret_access_key = myaccesskey
aws_accesskeyid = *****
aws_sessionToken = ****
region = ****
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass the profile to the `aws configure` command using `--profile` argument.

```
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key 'myaccesskey' --profile mfa
```

Reference:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what I need. I'm curious where can I find original documentation for this.

Comment: Updated the reference, see the line where it sets the region

Answer (score 1):

I use [this](https://github.com/broamski/aws-mfa) aws-mfa project.
This is a super easy python project for this exact kind of thing.

**Usage Example:**

Using command line arguments:

```
aws-mfa --duration 1800 --device arn:aws:iam::123456788990:mfa/dudeman
INFO - Using profile: default
INFO - Your credentials have expired, renewing.
Enter AWS MFA code for device [arn:aws:iam::123456788990:mfa/dudeman] (renewing for 1800 seconds):123456
INFO - Success! Your credentials will expire in 1800 seconds at: 2015-12-21 23:07:09+00:00
```

Using a profile: (profiles allow you to reference different sets of credentials, perhaps for different users or different regions):

```
aws-mfa --duration 1800 --device arn:aws:iam::123456788990:mfa/dudeman --profile development
INFO - Using profile: development
Enter AWS MFA code for device [arn:aws:iam::123456788990:mfa/dudeman] (renewing for 1800 seconds):666666
INFO - Success! Your credentials will expire in 1800 seconds at: 2015-12-21 23:09:04+00:00
```

Assuming a role:

```
aws-mfa --duration 1800 --device arn:aws:iam::123456788990:mfa/dudeman --assume-role arn:aws:iam::123456788990:role/some-role --role-session-name some-role-session
INFO - Validating credentials for profile: default  with assumed role arn:aws:iam::123456788990:role/some-role
INFO - Obtaining credentials for a new role or profile.
Enter AWS MFA code for device [arn:aws:iam::123456788990:mfa/dudeman] (renewing for 1800 seconds):123456
INFO - Success! Your credentials will expire in 1800 seconds at: 2016-10-24 18:58:17+00:00
```